# OpenTest Reporting Library

Tags: opentest

I am currently seeking information around the available reporting capabilities for OpenTest. I would need information regarding the following:

**Portability** of reports/logging - can these results be published in various formats

**Granularity** of reports/logging - is there a way of getting very detailed in what is reported on and/or strategies to ensure that enough information is logged to allow for debugging of automated tests and System Under Test(SUT)

**Screenshots** - is there current functionality to allow for screenshots to be taken and published/posted to external systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Portability of reports/logging

You can obtain the test session results by using the API, either in JSON format (which contains a lot of detail) or the JUnit XML format:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/session/<SESSION_ID>?format=json
http://localhost:3000/api/session/<SESSION_ID>?format=junit
```

The detailed log of the test session can be retrieved in: JSON or human-readable format:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/session/<SESSION_ID>/log?format=json
http://localhost:3000/api/session/<SESSION_ID>/log?format=pretty
```

### Granularity of reports/logging

The test results in JSON format will tell you everything you need to know about the pass/fail status for each test and each individual test action within a test, arguments that were used for test actions, the name of the screenshot captured for each test action, execution times and many other useful information.

When you want to troubleshoot a failed test, most of the time you'll need the detailed log information, which can be retrieved using the APIs I mentioned above. Aside from the log information generated by OpenTest itself, you can always log additional information that is specific to your application or test scenario using the [$log](https://getopentest.org/reference/javascript-api.html#logtext) JavaScript API.

### Screenshots

Screenshots are automatically captured for Web and UI tests, whenever a test action fails. If you need to capture additional screenshots during your test, you can do so using the `TakeScreenshot` keyword for either [Web testing](https://getopentest.org/reference/selenium-keywords.html#takescreenshot) or [mobile testing](https://getopentest.org/reference/appium-keywords.html#takescreenshot). You can also capture a screenshot after any test action by using the [$screenshot](https://getopentest.org/docs/global-arguments.html#screenshot) global test action argument:

```
- description: Click product 1 and capture a screenshot
  action: org.getopentest.selenium.Click
  args:
    locator: { id: product1 }
    $screenshot: true
```

You can download screenshots using this API:

```
https://localhost:3000/api/screenshot/SID1554380072_WEB_T05_SG01_ST01_after_03.png
```

`SID1554380072_WEB_T05_SG01_ST01_after_03.png` is the name of the screenshot file, which you can find in the test execution results in JSON format.

### Integrating with custom reporting solutions

At some point you will need to integrate with a dedicated reporting product that can give you all the nice features that OpenTest is not be able to provide out-of-the-box. This is possible to do using the APIs I described. In order to notify interested parties of the current status of test sessions, OpenTest also provides a WebSocket API. You can use that to be notified when a test session has finished, then you can extract all the information you need via APIs. You can find a Java project that does all that here: https://github.com/adrianth/opentest-monitor. This project is intended as a starting point for your own custom integration.